# Excluding columns from a dataframe based on column sums

Tags: r

I'm working on a data set that includes community data, and many of the columns (species) have a lot of zeroes. I would like to be able to drop these columns for some of the analyses I'm doing, based on the sum of the whole column.
I'm tempted to do this with a for loop, but I hear that the apply and by functions are better when you're using R.
My goal is to remove all columns with a sum of less than 15.
I have used `which()` to remove rows by factors, e.g.,

```
September<-which(data$Time_point=="September")

data<-data[-September,]
```

and the two ways I've tried removing columns is by using `apply()`:

```
data<-data[,apply(data,2,function(x)sum(x<=15))]
```

and by using a messy for loop/if else combo:

```
for (i in 6:length(data)){
    if (sum(data[,i])<=15)
    data[,i]<-NULL
    else 
    data[,i]<-data[,i]
    }
```

Neither of these methods has been working. Surely there is an elegant way to get rid of columns based on logical criteria?

```
str(head(data,10))
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ Core_num    : Factor w/ 159 levels "152","153","154",..: 133 72 70 75 89 85 86 90 95 99
 $ Cage_num    : num  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 $ Treatment   : Factor w/ 4 levels "","C","CC","NC": 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 $ Site        : Factor w/ 10 levels "","B","B07","B08",..: 1 8 8 8 7 7 7 7 9 9
 $ Time_point  : Factor w/ 3 levels "","May","September": 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 $ Spionidae   : num  108 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Syllidae    : num  185 0 0 0 3 8 0 1 4 1
 $ Opheliidae  : num  424 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
 $ Cossuridae  : num  164 0 7 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Sternaspidae: num  214 0 0 6 1 0 11 9 0 0
 $ Sabellidae  : num  1154 0 2 2 0 ...
 $ Capitellidae: num  256 1 10 17 0 3 0 0 0 0
 $ Dorvillidae : num  21 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Cirratulidae: num  17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Oligochaeta : num  3747 12 41 27 32 ...
 $ Nematoda    : num  410 5 4 13 0 0 0 2 2 0
 $ Sipuncula   : num  33 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Ostracoda   : num  335 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Decapoda    : num  62 0 4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Amphipoda   : num  2789 75 17 34 89 ...
 $ Copepoda    : num  75 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Tanaidacea  : num  84 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 $ Mollusca    : int  55 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you provided some reproducible data. For instance, the output of `str(head(data,10))` would probably be sufficient. (Printed versions of you data are generally useless, since they are difficult to copy+paste into examples, and they provide no information about how the data is _stored_, which can be crucial.)

Comment: Thanks @joran. I have edited the original question to contain that output. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What about a simple subset? First, we create a simple data frameL

```
R> dd = data.frame(x = runif(5), y = 20*runif(5), z=20*runif(5))
```

Then select the columns where the sum is greater than 15

```
R> dd1 = dd[,colSums(dd) > 15]
R> ncol(dd1)
[1] 2
```

In your data set, you only want to subset columns 6 onwards, so something like:

```
 ##Drop the first five columns
 dd[,colSums(dd[,6:ncol(dd)]) > 15]
```

or

```
 #Keep the first six columns
 cols_to_drop = c(rep(TRUE, 5), dd[,6:ncol(dd)]>15)
 dd[,cols_to_drop]
```

should work.

---

The key part to note is that in the square brackets, we want a vector of logicals, i.e. a vector of TRUE and FALSE. So if you wanted to subset using something a bit more complicated, then create a function that returns TRUE or FALSE and subset as usual.

Answer (score 9):

I've just had the same problem. Here's a solution using Tidyverse, in case you have both numeric and non numeric columns :

```
library(tidyverse)    
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(var1 = runif(10), var2 = rnorm(10), var3 = rlnorm(10), var4 = "notNumeric", var5 =0, var6 = FALSE )

dat %>% 
  select_if(negate(function(col) is.numeric(col) && sum(col) < 15))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to directly index your data.frame with a boolean and `colSums()`. For example:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(var1 = runif(10), var2 = rnorm(10), var3 = rlnorm(10))
colSums(dat)
#-----
     var1      var2      var3 
 5.782475  1.317914 12.91987
#Let's set the threshold at 5, so we should get var1 and var3
> dat[, colSums(dat) > 5]
#-----
        var1      var3
1  0.2875775 5.9709924
2  0.7883051 1.6451811
3  0.4089769 0.1399294
...
```

## EDIT - to address non-numeric columns

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(var1 = runif(10), var2 = rnorm(10), var3 = rlnorm(10), var4 = "notNumeric")

require(plyr)
dat[, -which(numcolwise(sum)(dat) < 5)]
```

Consolec:/documents and settings/charles/desktop/

```
> dat[, -which(numcolwise(sum)(dat) < 5)]
        var1      var3       var4
1  0.2875775 5.9709924 notNumeric
2  0.7883051 1.6451811 notNumeric
3  0.4089769 0.1399294 notNumeric
.....
```

Comment: Cue the OP saying it didn't work on their data set in 3...2...1...(look at the first 6 columns of their data frame).

Comment: `data[,c(1:5, colSums(data[, 6:length(data)]>15])]`.  The apply version would be similar but I think `colSums` is faster.

Comment: @joran - bah, good point. Without thinking too much, this should work `require(plyr); dat[, -which(numcolwise(sum(dat) < threshold))]`

Comment: @Justin - yeah that would work, though I am always hesitant to hardcode column names/numbers since they become much use generalizable then.

Comment: @Chase same here.  I usually use `numcolwise` too if I'm making things reusable.  But often I like the check (and associated errors) that hard coded column names give me if I am using it in a script for report output or something.

Answer (score 3):

This will give back the columns that don't contain all zeros including factors and character columns (I only read in the first rowchunky thing of your data):

Read in some of your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="  Core_num Cage_num Treatment Site Time_point Spionidae Nereididae Syllidae Opheliidae
6        24        1         C   M2        May         0          0        0          0
4        22        2         C   M2        May         0          0        0          1
9        27        3         C   M2        May         0          0        0          0
23       41        4         C    M        May         0          0        3          0
19       37        5         C    M        May         0          0        8          0
20       38        6         C    M        May         0          0        0          1",  header=T)
```

The code:

```
summer <- function(x){
    if(is.numeric(x)){
        sum(x) > 15
    } else {
        TRUE
    }
}

dat[, sapply(dat,  summer)]
```